# how to implement Grid system in wordpress on the_content()

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to implement grid system in the wordpress content. I want to save columns content column by columns it and retrieve it from the database column by columns.Some columns need to customized not store in database and some columns needs to customize and store it in the database.This should be done instead of `the_content()`.

`the_content()`-this will retrieve or store the entire content part.

But what i want is I want to separate the content in the grid format with multiple columns and rows.

Comment: There are **many** ways to achieve this,but I dont see your effort, not even an idea, how you would like to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was trying to do as the template. I tried ACF plugin. But What I am trying to do is If I edit some columns need to customized not store in database it should affect is all places where the template is used.Some columns content needs to customize and store it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve that is probably to use custom fields. This way you can have content in separate fields. You can use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for it or code custom metaboxes yourself and then just output values on your page/post template files the way you want.

You can also use visual composer to compose layout for each page easily, but I am not a big fan of it. I might be biased.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried ACF plugin. But What I am trying to do is If I edit some columns need to customized not store in database it should affect is all places where the template is used.Some columns content needs to customize and store it in the database.So I was trying to do as the template.

Comment: Then you can create a theme options page (can do easily with acf pro) and have custom fields there and output those option fields on templates so they will be everywhere. Or you can hardcode fixed content directly into the template.